# Blank node and graph

Tags: rdf, protege, blank-nodes

I always faced the problem of adding a blank node and grouping some RDF triples in different RDF graph, for that I would like to ask this question:
can we add blank node to an ontology and can we group the RDF triples of an ontology in different RDF graph using Protégé?

Comment: First, Protege is not an RDF editor. If you are talking about blank nodes with same labels in different files, those blank nodes are different, see tag info. But if you are talking about RDF named graphs, then the question is interesting. I *suppose* that blank nodes with same labels in different named graphs should be the same blank node.

Comment: @StanislavKralin that isn't guaranteed. Blank node scope is limited to an RDF graph, the same label in different RDF graphs doesn't mean the same entity.

Comment: @marco it's unclear what you're asking with a concrete example. As StanislavKralin said, Protege is an OWL ontoloy editor, blank nodes are part of RDF. what you mean by *"group the rdf triples of an ontology in different rdf graph"* ? that is totally unclear. the is no concept of RDF graph in OWL. you can create different ontologies to modularize the doamin you want to model.

Comment: @AKSW, yes, obviously, blank node labels are locally scoped, but I'm not sure that the scope is RDF graph. I can't find an unumbiguous requirement in the specs... Maybe 3.5 and 3.6 in https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts

Comment: first of all thank for all your comments. @AKSW  I know that I can resolve this problem by creating different ontology  but in my case I can't do that, I will try to use rdf editor to see if I can resolve my problem